# Problemas recolección datos Comercio Electrónico Avanzado Google Analytics

Tags: google-analytics

Estoy implementando el comercio electronico de Google Analytics y tengo un problema.
Cuando se realiza la compra de un producto este redirecciona a una página de gracias y ahí es donde se envía el evento Purchase para registrar dicha compra en Analytics.

```
ga('require', 'ec');
ga('set', 'currencyCode', 'EUR');    
ga('ec:addProduct', {
    'id': 'prueba-001',
    'name': 'Prueba',
    'brand': 'Prueba',
    'category': 'Prueba',
    'variant': 'Prueba',
    'price': 10.50
});
ga('ec:setAction', 'purchase', {
    'id': 't-prueba-01',
    'revenue': 5.50
});
ga('send', 'pageview');
```

El evento de 'purchase' se registra perfectamente, pero el de addProduct no del todo bien, se registra las compras únicas de cada producto pero nada más.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

No sé que más hacer, he seguido los pasos de la [documentación](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/enhanced-ecommerce?hl=es-419) y el problema persiste.

Answer (score 0):

Solucionado, el problema era que en el evento `ga('ec:addProduct'` tenía que añadir el campo y el valor `quantity: 1,`. En la documentación no ponía que fuese obligatorio, por eso no lo había incluido.